# How to create a dynamic-width arrow in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I need to write a page that has a full-width arrow on the bottom of the page. Thus, I use the following HTML:

```
<div id="footer_wrap">
    <div id="footer_left"></div>
    <div id="footer_right"></div>
</div>
```

the relevant CSS being:

```css
#footer_wrap{
width: 100%;
}

#footer_left{
background: url('../img/arrow_bg1.png') repeat-x;
width: 100%;
height: 183px;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
}

#footer_right{
display: inline-block;
background: url('../img/arrow_bg2.png') no-repeat;
width: 250px;
height: 183px;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
}
```

In theory, this should work - and indeed, it did, when I used images with fixed background colors. However, my client required them to be transparent, which unfortunately revealed the ugly truth behind my hack - the arrow's "shaft" peeks out of the arrow head. What can I do about it?

The images comprising the arrow are a 1x183px "shaft" texture that is repeated for the entire length of the arrow (or, in this case, the entire page `[width: 100%]`), and the arrowhead is a 250x183px rectangle.

The arrow needs to take up the entire page and it needs to use transparent images, so these solutions are out of the window immediately. I suppose something like `width: 100%-250px` would be acceptable, but these shenanigans aren't supported in CSS.

Comment: Do you need crossbrowser-support, or can you use something like `box-sizing: border-box; padding-right: 250px;` on the footer_left?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're already using position:absolute; so instead of `width:100%`, you can set `left` and `right`:

```
#footer_left{
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right:250px;
/* etc */
}
```

There are many other workarounds, but for your specific case i think it's the easiest.

Comment: Way neater solution. Again though, make sure the "width" is the same with the "right". My experience says is good practice to put a comment by both values.

Answer (score 0):

I think this method might work: http://jsfiddle.net/27p4e/

```
<div class="footer">
 <div class="footer-left">left</div>
 <div class="footer-right">right</div>
</div>

.footer {
width:100%;
height:183px;
overflow:auto;
background:#ccc;
display:table;
}

.footer-left {
display:table-cell;
background:red;
height:183px;
}
.footer-right {
display:table-cell;
width:250px;
height:183px;
background:blue;
}
```